# How to return nearest element from an ordered set?

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point

I have a vector which contains some floating point values reasonably apart from each other and sorted according to some function. For example,

```
double foo(double x)
{
   return 199.1*x;
}
double x = 3000000.3157;
double y = x + DBL_EPSILON;

std::vector<double> s { y,y+10};
std::sort(s.begin(),s.end(),[](double x,double y) { return foo(x) < foo(y) ;} );
```

Now someone has a key which is close to the one I have in `s`, such as `x`. In the era of [lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), all have their own little function to search, like

```
std::cout<<std::distance(s.begin(),std::lower_bound(s.begin(),s.end(),x,
[] (double x,double y) { return foo(x) < foo(y);}))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::distance(s.begin(),std::lower_bound(s.begin(),s.end(),x,
[] (double x,double y) { double f1 = foo(x);
                         double f2 = foo(y);
                         return f1 < f2;}))<<std::endl;
```

and gets different position (and the corresponding values are very different).

While looking at the usage, it appeared, they are related to **finding for a key `k`**

- **Nearest element from an ordered set of well-placed floating point values.**
- **A ratio, `r`, which (ideally should be [0,1] ) attached to consecutive values `x1` & `x2` such that return value of a function `f(x1,x2,r)` is approximately equal to `k`.**

Both of them looks like related, and related to interpolation. How do I implement them?

NOTE:

In the short code below

```
double f1 = foo(x);
double f2 = foo(y);
bool l = foo(x) < foo(y);
std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<(f1<f2)<< " "<<l<<" "<<(f1 == f2) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (foo(x) < foo(y)) << " "<< (foo(y) < foo(x))
          << " "<<(foo(x) == foo(y) )<<std::endl;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::isless(foo(x) , foo(y))
          << " "<< std::isless(foo(y) , foo(x)) <<std::endl;
```

I get output with [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) on a X86 machine as

```
false true true
true true false
false false
```

While my guess is that GCC does higher precision (80bit) on the fly unless I force it to store the result, resulting different result for `l` & `(f1<f2)` (which caused the problem stated above) . I will also be interested to know why `foo(x) < foo(y)` and `foo(y) < foo(x)` both says `true`!

Comment: Aside from rounding differences for numbers that are very close together, your `foo(x)` is semantically equivalent to just sorting by the numbers themselves... If `x < y`, then `kx < ky` for any `k > 0`...

Comment: That is just an example. In actual code it was a set of geometric points sorted by their y axis intercept along a given angle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two statements accomplish nothing, because `DBL_EPSILON` is smaller than 1ulp for these numbers:

```
double x = 3000000.3157;
double y = x + DBL_EPSILON;
```

To be sure, I printed the hexadecimal representation of both `x` and `y` and got the following:

```
4146E3602868DB8C
4146E3602868DB8C
```

When I run the example at the bottom of your question through a couple different versions of G++ (4.4.5 and 4.8.0) with optimization both on (-O3) and off (no flags), I get the following output:

```
false false true
false false true
0 0
```

I suspect the behavior you're seeing is for precisely the reason you postulate:  Your compiler is carrying greater precision for intermediate results and that's bleeding through to these comparisons.

What version of the compiler are you using, and does other code in the application adjust any of the rounding modes?  What compile flags are you using?

---

**EDIT 1**

I was able to reproduce your behavior by recompiling with optimization *off* and in 32-bit mode.  In that mode, I see that the compiler leaves the result of `foo` on the floating point stack:

```
_Z3food:
.LFB1053:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp    #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp  #,
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $8, %esp    #,
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax   # x, tmp61
    movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)  # tmp61, x
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax  # x, tmp62
    movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)  # tmp62, x
    fldl    -8(%ebp)    # x
    fldl    .LC0    #
    fmulp   %st, %st(1) #,
    leave
```

That suggests that this is a quirk of the i386 ABI.  To test this theory, I looked at the i386 ABI more closely.  On [page 38 of this PDF](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf) (aka. "page 3-12" by the internal page numbers), I find what is likely the smoking gun:

> `%st(0)` *Floating-point return values* appear on the top of the
>            floating- point register stack; there is no difference in the
>            representation of single- or double-precision values in floating-point
>            registers. If the function does not return a floating-point value,
>            then this register must be empty. This register must be empty before G
>            entry to a function.

It goes on to say a few paragraphs later:

> A floating-point return value appears on the top of the Intel387
>   register stack. The caller then must remove the value from the
>   Intel387 stack, even if it doesn’t use the value. Failure of either
>   side to meet its obligations leads to undefined program behavior. The
>   standard calling sequence does not include any method to detect such
>   failures nor to detect return value type mismatches. Therefore the
>   user must declare all functions properly. **There is no difference in
>   the representation of single-, double- or extended-precision values in
>   floating-point registers.**

Searching further down to pages 3-27 (PDF page 53) and 3-28 (PDF page 54) give the following confusing twists.  The table in Figure 3-30 suggests that the initial rounding mode is "53-bit (double precision)", and that that's the mode at process initialization.

It goes on further to give the following warning on the next page:

> The initial floating-point state should be changed with care. In
>   particular, many floating-point routines may produce undefined
>   behavior if the precision control is set to less than 53 bits. The
>   _fpstart routine (see Chapter 6) **changes the precision control to 64 bits** and sets all exceptions to be asked. This is the default state
>   required for conformance to the ANSI C standard and to the IEEE 754
>   Floating-point standard.

A [couple](http://www.vinc17.org/research/extended.en.html) [reference](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_70.html)s on the net indicate Linux does indeed set the x87 to extended precision (at least in the 32-bit ABI).

---

**EDIT 2**

It appears extended precision is indeed the culprit.  I added the following code to the test case, [as suggested by this page](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_70.html):

```
void set_fpu (unsigned int mode)
{
      asm ("fldcw %0" : : "m" (*&mode));
}

// ...

set_fpu(0x27F);
```

With those lines added, the test case returns the same values I saw with the 64-bit ABI.

So, assuming you're compiling a 32-bit program under Linux, this appears to be the reason you're seeing strange comparison and sorting results.

Can you re-run your sorting and searching code with the FPU set to 53-bit precision as I did above, and see if that resolves the differences you saw between your two lambda expressions?

Comment: Aha, I was able to reproduce the weird behavior by compiling with `g++ -m32`.  The 64-bit compiler doesn't show the strange behavior, but the 32-bit compiler does.  Digging into the generated code now.

Comment: @EricPostpischil:  I believe excess precision explains it nicely, if you allow the floating point processor to return values on the stack.  If you see my edited answer above, the default i386 ABI apparently does this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: This page appears relevant as well:  http://www.vinc17.org/research/extended.en.html

Comment: I guess gcc with x86 does return those 80bit registers. If i remember correctly they also have a flag to turn it off for C99 as the language species. However what makes both 'foo(x)< foo(y)' and 'foo(y)<foo(x)' return true(or false)?

Comment: I would expect `foo(x)` to be equal to `foo(y)` if they're both the same precision, and so `foo(x) < foo(y)` should be false.  If one of these values is at extended precision relative to the other, rounded value, then one will be larger or smaller than the other depending on whether the rounded value was rounded up or down.  As for which value is extended precision?  That's a function of the evaluation order.  If the compiler happened to evaluate left-to-right, the the left value is rounded and the right value is not.  Switching `x` and `y` wouldn't make a difference in that case.

Comment: @abir : Note that inconsistent comparison operations like this can really, really mess up the standard containers and standard algorithms.  They rely on less-than being a consistent operation.  If you can get any NaNs in your data, you could end up in some real trouble.  :-)

Comment: @user2638924: What likely happens is that, in `foo(x) < foo(y)`, `foo(x)` is calculated and then stored somewhere temporarily in a way that removes the excess precision (thus producing, in this case, a slightly smaller number). Then `foo(y)` is calculated. It is not moved to a temporary location, and all of its precision is retained. Then the saved `foo(x)` is compared to the raw `foo(y)`, producing true for less-than. When `foo(y) < foo(x)` is evaluated, it is `foo(y)` that is stored, leading to another true result.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : BTW, I'm JoeZ.  Something happened to my user account just now.  Hopefully it's just a transient database issue...

Comment: I removed my earlier comment because my memory about the `return` statement was faulty. Casts and assignments are required to remove excess precision. `return` statements are not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is debatable whether the reasons that make assignment remove excess precision do not make `return` remove excess precision too. C99 says of the returned expression “If the expression has a type different from the return type of the function in which it appears, the value is converted as if by assignment” (6.8.6.4:3). C++ n3376 says “The value of the expression is implicitly converted to the return type of the function in which it appears”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil A perverse person could argue that in C99 with FLT_EVAL_METHOD=2, `double f() { return 0.1; }` should return the `long double` approximation of 0.1 (since 0.1 represents this value and has the same type as the return type of the function), whereas `…return 0.1L; }` should return the `double` approximation of 0.1 (since `0.1L` has type `long double`, different from `double`, so the value should be converted “as if by assignment”)

Comment: @PascalCuoq: C 2011 (N1570) note 160 says “The **return** statement is not an assignment.… The representation of floating-point values may have wider range or precision than implied by the type; a cast may be used to remove this extra range and precision.”